# HOW TO ADD A NEW BLANK PAGE IN FPDF

Tags: fpdf, page-break

I'm currently having a trouble configuring this FPDF project. I want to add a new blank page in my fpdf file. It is like an adding a new page but I don't want to insert my header and footer in it. What should I do? Please help me. Big thanks!

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we don't write code for you.**

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. If you have defined headers and footers they are going to be added when you add a page. Please [edit] your question and include what you have now, what isn't working and what the desired result is.